# Significance of Marriage in Hindu life

Tags: marriage, life

In Hindu life marriage is 'Sanskar' … RSS Sarkaryavah Dattatreya Hosabale.(PTI) What does Sankar means in this statement?

Comment: Samskara is a a purificatory rite. Marriage is one among the 16 Hindu Samskaras.

Answer (score 4):

Samskar means a religious sacrament that has its own import . It  supposedly  purifies the mind , and routes a person in the path of spritual progress.

> The mere knowledge of the rules of Dharma, however does not make a man
> 'Dharmishta' i.e., a man acting always in conformity with Dharma. Therefore, Dharma has to be ingrained in the mind of every individual.
> Adi Shankara in his commentary on Vedanta Sutra has explained this process
> thus:- 
> संस्कारो हि नाम गुणाधानेन वा स्याद् दोषापनयनेन वा।
> Samskara is a process by which good qualities are generated and bad
> qualities are removed in an individual.
>
> It is highlighted by a promise which a bridegroom was required to make while
> undergoing the vivaha Samskara. While giving the girl in marriage, the father,  addresses the bridegroom with the following words:
> धर्मे चार्थे च कामे च नातिचरितव्या त्वयेयम्।।
> You shall not transgress Dharma in the attainment of Artha and Kama.
> The bridegroom accepts the condition with these words:
> नातिचरामि।।
>
> I shall not transgress Dharma, in matters of Artha and Kama. 
> The promise taken indicates that the purpose of marriage was the fulfillment of
> Trivarga doctrine throughout the life of husband and wife. This aspect is brought out in
> the' Saptapadi ', (the ceremony of taking seven steps by the bride) at the end of which
> there is a declaration that they become life long friends. 
> अन्योन्यस्याव्यभिचारो भवेदामरणान्तिकः।
> एष धर्मः समासेन ज्ञेयः स्त्रीपुंसयोः परः।।
> संतुष्टो भार्यया भर्ता भर्त्रा भार्या तथैव च।
> यस्मिन्न्ौव कुले नित्यं कल्याणं तत्र वै ध्रुवम्।।(Manu Smriti 9.101,3.60)
> Mutual friendship and fidelity is the highest Dharma to be observed by
> husband and wife, throughout their life.
>
> The family in which husband and wife have mutual affection and respect
> always secures happiness and prosperity. 
> The observance of the above directive throughout life by the husband
> and the wife is not only conducive to happiness and harmony in family life, but also
> essential for national or social life.
> [Dharma The Global Ethic](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Dharma_the_Global_Ethic.html?id=bzRolpXvB_EC&redir_esc=y)
> *By
> M. Rama Jois
> (Former Chief Justice, Punjab & Haryana)*

PS - Vivaha Samskara is a gateway to indulge in dharmik activities and attain punya , ( also in tradition, to clear off debts to Pitr, to perform yajnas ,and to support the members of other ashramas).